# I am having problem in compiling the program. It is not making .exe file and is showing the following thing

Tags: c, compilation, executable

[problem in .exe file of program_1. It is not creating a executable file after typing "gcc program_1.c -o program-1".It is showing the following thing in the picture but for main.c ,it had created the executable file .So please resolve my problem.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a2CK9.png)

Comment: Please post everything (The code, the error message and other related things) *in the question, as text*. And not as a link to an image.

Comment: Google out undefined Winmain

Answer (score 0):

The reference to WinMain@16 means that you are linking as a Windows application, not a Console application. I don't use MINGW, but you should check how to set the application type.

Answer (score 0):

I see it returns a 1. When coding using C, a preferred practice is to include this line of code at the end of the main:

```
 return 0;
```

With the purpose of telling the OS that your program executed successfully. Also you don't have a return type to your main, you can choose between depending if you want to return an int or nothing:

```
int main()
void main()
```